# Mono on VS2010?

Tags: c#, mono, installation, cross-platform

I want to start doing a cross platform project that will run on Linux and Windows.

I went to mono's website to check things out as I heard mono allows me to run c# on Linux, but when I arrived there http://mono-project.com/Main_Page I was a bit confused.

The download page allows me to download it just fine but in order to program mono on VS2010 I need to pay for mono-tools or are there any alternatives within VS2010 ?

In short what do I need to be able to use mono with VS2010 and what are the alternatives to programming mono without VS2010 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can develop in Linux using [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).

You can also develop on Windows using Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition, and target the Microsoft .NET Framework.  You can then run your assemblies through the [Mono Migration Analyzer (MoMA)](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) to make sure they'll run successfully on Linux/Mono.  Since Mono uses the same standard IL as the Microsoft framework, the application will run unchanged on Linux, provided you stick to supported portions of the framework.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have vs2010 ultimate available would you happen to be able to guide me on how do I target the mono framework or is there a how to for it already that you could link me to ? I was already aware of the Mono Migration Analyzer tool ;) which was what made me want to make my application in mono hehehe, just not sure how it goes yet.

Comment: @Guapo: You just do a normal .NET application/library.  You don't have to "target mono" - the whole goal of mono is to run standard .NET apps unchanged...

Comment: I got the point now, so in the long run basic all I need is to make sure everything is Compatible with mono in my application. Thanks.

Comment: @Guapo: Exactly.  As long as MoMA says everything's good, you can just run it directly.

Comment: I would still recommend running it under Linux since MoMA doesn't always catch all incompatibilities.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything special in your .NET development in order to use mono (aside from writing compatible code).  Mono is simply a free implementation of the .NET framework, which will simply *run* applications written for .NET, regardless of underlying OS platform (i.e. Linux).

Basically, you just need to develop your .NET application as normal, and then you can *run* that application on mono if you so choose.  Since Mono is it's own implementation, there may be some differences, and you can use the [Mono compatibility too](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA)l to ensure that the .NET code you've written is compatible with Mono's implementation of the .NET framework.

You may also want to [download a VMWare image of Mono](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) or something similar if you'd like to spin up a Linux virtual machine for testing of how your application actually runs on a Mono-enabled machine once you've started development.